# Why does the array only display garbage value

Tags: arrays, c

The C program(`main` function)asks the user for the number of elements in an array(which this function works). The C function `findSecondSmallest` finds the second smallest element of an array(points toward the first index). The C function `sortAscending` arranges the array elements in ascending order (does not display the inputted elements, just garbage values) and the C function `displayArray` should display the arranged array in ascending order.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
int initializeArray(int num,int arr[]);
int findSecondSmallest(int num,int arr[]);
int *sortAscending(int num,int arr[]);
void displayArray(int num,int arr[]);
void main(){
    int array[50],*arr;
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    initializeArray(n,array);
    findSecondSmallest(n,array);
    arr = sortAscending(n,array);
    displayArray(n,arr);
}

int initializeArray(int num,int arr[]){
    int i;
    printf("Input the number of elements in an array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\nEnter %d elements: ", num);
    for(i = 0;i < num;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
}

int findSecondSmallest(int num,int arr[]){
    int i,secondSmall,small;
    small = secondSmall = INT_MAX;
    for(i = 1;i < num;i++){
        if(arr[i] < small){
            secondSmall = small;
            small = arr[i];
        }else if(arr[i] < secondSmall && arr[i] > small){
            secondSmall = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The second smallest element is %d", secondSmall);
}


int *sortAscending(int num,int arr[]){
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i = 0;i < num;i++){
        for(j = i + 1;j < num;j++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void displayArray(int num,int arr[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < num;i++){
        printf("Element at Array[%d] = %d ", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

In need of help

Comment: The user is only entering the first `num` elements, but you're sorting the entire array, which includes all the garbage values that weren't filled in.

Comment: Have `initialize_array` return `num`, then use that when you call the other functions.

Comment: Why is `findSecondSmallest` starting from `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`?

Comment: is it not ```i = 1``` ?

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`. Look at your loops in `initializeArray` and `displayArray`.

Comment: If you want to get the second smallest, why don't you do that *after* you sort the array? Then it will just be the second element in the array.

Comment: our instructor told us that `findSecondSmallest` should be executed first before `sortAscending`

Comment: I actually changed it to 0, still prints 0

Comment: I never said that had anything to do with your problem. The reason for your problem is because you're printing more elements than the user filled in, unless they input 50 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to process only the elements that the user input, not the entire array, since the rest of the array is uninitialized.

Change `initializeArray()` to return the number of elements that the user input. Then use that instead of `n` when calling the other functions.

`initializeArray()` wasn't using the parameter `num`. It should use that to check that the user doesn't enter more elements than the array can hold. So you need to use a different variable for the parameter and the user's input, so you can compare them.

`findSecondSmallest()` doesn't return anything, so it should be declared `void`, not `int`.

`sortAscending()` is supposed to return a pointer to the array, but it was missing the `return` statement.

In `findSecondSmallest()` you can initialize the variables to the first element of the array rather than `INT_MAX`. Then it makes sense to start your loop from `i = 1`, since you've already used element `0`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initializeArray(int num,int arr[]);
void findSecondSmallest(int num,int arr[]);
int *sortAscending(int num,int arr[]);
void displayArray(int num,int arr[]);

int main(void){
    int array[50],*arr;
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    int num = initializeArray(n,array);
    findSecondSmallest(num,array);
    arr = sortAscending(num,array);
    displayArray(num,arr);
}

int initializeArray(int n,int arr[]){
    int i, num;
    printf("Input the number of elements in an array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > n) {
        printf("That's too many elements\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nEnter %d elements: ", num);
    for(i = 0;i < num;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    return num;
}

void findSecondSmallest(int num,int arr[]){
    int i,secondSmall,small;
    small = secondSmall = arr[0];
    for(i = 1;i < num;i++){
        if(arr[i] < small){
            secondSmall = small;
            small = arr[i];
        }else if(arr[i] < secondSmall && arr[i] > small){
            secondSmall = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The second smallest element is %d\n", secondSmall);
}


int *sortAscending(int num,int arr[]){
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i = 0;i < num;i++){
        for(j = i + 1;j < num;j++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

void displayArray(int num,int arr[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < num;i++){
        printf("Element at Array[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```